# How to always trust software during install?

Tags: windows-7, installation, security, uac, windows-installer

I am installing a program, and I keep getting this prompt:

```
Would you like to install this device software?
Name: Juno LTD. Jungo Connectivity
Publisher: Atmel Norway

[✓] Always trust software from "Atmel Norway"  [Install] [Don't install]
```

I have checked "Always trust software" and selected install, but I continue to get the same prompt. I've probably hit "Always trust software" and "install" at least 20 times during installation of this one program, but the same problem continues.

I know one way I could get around this would be to change my UAC settings to never notify me when a program makes changes, install the software, then change UAC back. However, this requires me to restart my computer first, which means I would have to cancel this installation. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known issue in both Atmel Studio and windows 7. After some research, I found [this Atmel thread](http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/Multiple-Windows-security-dialog-boxes-during-driver-install-on-Windows-7) where someone complained about the same issue. The answer on that site linked to [this windows support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2921916) with a link to a windows quickfix. After downloading and installing that quickfix, everything runs great for me.